# How to send a POST request to an EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, amazon-ec2, postman

I have created a simple API in node and deployed it on an ubuntu based EC2 instance. I also installed node js on my EC2. I've been trying to send a POST request from POSTMAN, with a JSON file. My API will extract the required data from the received POST request and will store it on a Mongo Atlas server. I copied my private IP address of EC2 instance and used it in POSTMAN. All I could get is a 'session timed out' message on POSTMAN.

[POSTMAN,EC2 IMAGES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwJbl.png)

I just need to be able to send a POST request to my EC2 instance.

Here's my server code:

```
const http = require('http'); const app=require('./app.js');
const port=process.env.PORT || 3001;
const server=http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
```

This is my url format:

```
https://ec2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/products
```

For this, I get this error on POSTMAN:

> Error: Request timed out.

And when I try a different format `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/3001/products`, I get a different error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED.

I think there's something wrong with my format, I am not sure.

[inbound-rules-picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3C5v.png)

[inbound rules-picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYfej.png)

Comment: " I copied my private IP address" a private IP is just that - private.  It cannot be accessed by the internet, only via private networks such as the VPC, peered VPCs, or a VPN.  Use the instance's public IP.  I recommend you open the security group only to yourself while you experiment and develop.

Comment: i did that too, it didn't work either

Comment: Application has to listen on all addresses ( 0.0.0.0 ).  System must allow the incoming connections through the firewall if any.  Instance must have a public IP address.  Security group must allow your client address.  That's it.  Timeout generally indicates dropped packets or unreachable IPs.  Connection Refused indicates the port was recached but not listening.  Not much more we can say without seeing debugging information.

Comment: in your screenshot it looks like you're connecting to `<redacted>/3000` and maybe that should be port `<redacted>:3000`, not path `<redacted>/3000`.  Unspecified, the port will be the default for the service (80 for http, 443 for https).  So there's the likely reason for the timeout behavior.

Comment: Try `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:3001/products`

Answer (score 1):

The attempts you have made on the 2 different `format` is expected as they are not the same.

In the first one `https://ec2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/products`, you are attempting to make an **HTTPS** connection with TCP port **3001** on your EC2 instance. For this to work, your instance need to listen on port 3001 using HTTPS. Also your security group should allow this port which the screenshot is not showing. Hence this attempt errors as "Timeout". Your TCP connection is not getting established here due to insufficient Inbound rules in your security group.

[image]

Second one is where you mentioned the path only as `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/3001/products` so it is not easy to say about the protocol but taking an assumption that it is **HTTP**. So the second attempts says that you are hitting the IP address using protocol HTTP. Since no port is mentioned, it is defaulting to port **80**. This port is allowed in your Security Group letting your POSTMAN client to "reach" the instance. Since there is no web application listening on port 80 [Your app configuration shows the port as 3001], it is giving back a RESET which is what is showing up as `Error Connection Refused`.

Solution for your case [With the information shared so far] will be as below:

1. Open up your security group also to allow 3001 port. You will have to use Custom TCP selection from drop down and then mention port number as 3001.
2. After the above is added, attempt `http://ec2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:3001/products` . Note the protocol is **http** and not **https**. I am also assuming that your laptop is not behind your office network which might block non-standard ports of 3001.

Comment: I added a new inbound rule, with custom TCP and 3001 as PORT number. Everything works fine now, thank you all for your suggestions!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For your EC2 instance to be able to receive HTTP requests from the Internet:

- The EC2 instance needs to be in a **public subnet**
- The EC2 needs a **public IP address**
- The **Security Group** associated with the EC2 instance should permit Inbound traffic on port 80 from a source of `0.0.0.0/0` (or, for testing purposes, just the public IP address associated with your own computer -- use https://icanhazip.com/)

If it still isn't working, try connecting to the EC2 instance and do a `curl localhost` to confirm that the web server is working.

Comment: I tried again with public address, now I am left with this-Error: connect ECONNREFUSED, and this is my url format: xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/3001/products. Is this the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the security group attached to your `EC2 Instance` and has an inbound tcp rule open to port 3001